# Use Dynamics AX array in .Net

Tags: .net, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

We have an installation of Dynamics AX 4 that's being called by a web service, and I need to retrieve a collection of table buffers.

While I could instantiate a class instance and return all the buffers that meet my criteria one by one, I've found there's a lot of overhead in the process and I would like to pass a collection instead.

I'm aware that in the Business Connector I have access to AxaptaContainer, but in AX a container can't hold objects/buffers so it doesn't do me a whole lot of good.

Is there any good way to pass a collection to .Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone cares, I was never able to build a collection of .Net objects within AX and pass the collection back to a web service, even if they were defined within the service.

Instead, I built XML representations of the AX objects and handed off what was essentially KeyValuePairs for mapping and looped through the object collection so their values could be mapped object by object and the collection was built in a strongly-typed object within the service.

Answer (score 0):

This is too late for a reply. But I think you can use the List object in X++ and return it back to .Net. Note that the List object has a method called getEnumerator which can be used to traverse through its contents.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, List would get passed as AxaptaObject and I would run through the type question all over again.

Comment: Well, that is wierd. I will try this once I get some free time and share the results. :)